# echo certain text from php links

Tags: php

I have:

```
<a href="index.php?mypage=one">one</a>
```

And:

```
<a href="index.php?mypage=two">two</a>
```

PHP page:

```
<?php
if mypage=one then 
echo "my stuff text........one";

if mypage=two then
echo "my stuff text........two";
?>
```

I want to get text separately for each link from same php page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, **if then** construct is not available in PHP so your code is syntactically wrong. The use of switch as suggested already is a good way to go. However, for your problem, you should use $_GET['mypage'] instead of $_POST['mypage']. It seems you are beginning PHP. Once you get some good basics, you will probably be making use of the functions such as include() and require(). Make sure you do not make mistakes beginners do:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['mypage'])
{
    @include($_GET['mypage']);
}
?>
```

The above code works and looks simple but it has a very dangerous implementation allowing the malicious users to perform an attack known as file inclusion attack. So you should try to use the switch statements such as:

```
<?php
$mypage = $_GET['mypage']; //also you might want to cleanup $mypage variable
switch($mypage)
{
    case "one":
        @include("one.php");
        break;

    case "two":
        @include("two.php");
        break;

    default:
        @include("404.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Umm, that php is not even remotely valid code. You want a [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
<?php
$mypage = isset($_GET['mypage']) ? $_GET['mypage'] : '';
switch ($mypage) {
case 'one':
    echo "my stuff text........one";
    break;
case 'two':
    echo "my stuff text........two";
    break;
default:
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo 'This page does not exist';
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. +1 for a thorough answer.